# Storing multiple strings in a class hierarchy designed to hold a single string

Tags: java

I have a hierarchy of classes. Each class represent different kind of question in a survey.

Up until now, users can give a single answer to a question (via input box, ratio button or from a dropdown). The answer to each asked question is stored as a string in the `answer` field inherited from `Question`.

I have been tasked with adding a MultiChoice question to the hierarchy. A multi choise question enable users to provide multiple answers (such as by selecting multiple options in a group of checkboxes, or via multiple text boxes).

In the diagram below, the green class is the one I need to add. My problem is that the current structure assumes a single answer only.

I've thought of two possible modifications:

- Encoding multiple answers as a csv and store them in the `answer` field.
- Introducing a new field `list<String> answers` and adding an getter `getAnswers()` to `MultiChoice`.

I see problems with both approaches. The first one adds the responsability of parsing a possible csv of answers to the caller. The second one violates the Liskov substitution principle.

My question is: How can I support multiple answers in `MultiChoice` without introducing such problems?

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, a question should be able to accept multiple answers for the same question?  Or is it like a multi choice where only one answer is actually chosen from a list of possible answers?  Will the format be "select all that apply" or "select the correct choice"

Comment: How does it break **Liskov Substitution Principal** !

Comment: Move `MultiChoice` into separate hierarchy and update client code so it will know how to work with both `Single-` and `Multi-` kinds of questions/answers?

Comment: Multiple answers for the same question. Think of being asked to mark one or more checkboxes which indicate your answers.

Comment: @NeerajJain `setAnswer` and `getAnswer` would need to be disabled in MultiChoice (not implemented exception?). That causes a violation of LSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is of course to change the interface to

```
List<String> getAnswers();
void addAnswer(String answer);
```

But that's still a struct rather than object oriented design. To me this rather feels like a case for a visitor pattern with just having a interface like

```
void accept(Visitor v);
```

and a vistor interface like

```
interface Visitor<T> {
  T visit(T arg, DropDown answer);
  T visit(T arg, MultiChoice answer);
  T visit(T arg, SingleChoice answer);
  ...
}
```

with a visit method per concrete answer type. And then implement each statistics on the answers as a implementation of Visitor if statistics is what you wanna do. However, always think in what you wanna do with the data, not in dump fields.

Comment: Thank you. I settled with returning an Iterator to a list.